# Does datetime have a way to say the date is unspecified?

Tags: python, datetime

In processing some files I have found that there is a specific code used (a very high number) to specify that the datetime has no value (for example, an event may have a start but no specified end time or an event that exists but is unscheduled). Currently my code just returns that code but I am looking for a better way to represent it that doesn't require checking if that value is not a datetime.

Currently I'm looking at possibly using `datetime.datetime.max` or `datetime.datetime.min`, but this would be a sub-optimal option.

Does the datetime module have a builtin way to represent this?

Comment: Have you considered using None?

Comment: None is not optimal because that's how a value from the file is identified if it isn't provided at all. So if you ask for a value and it wasn't provided you get None, so preferably an unspecified value shouldn't be None.

Comment: I can think of multiple things that work (like an extension of the datetime class with the value, a constant to compare against, etc., I just want to know if datatime has a built in way to do this already so I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I looked but didn't see anything.  `datetime` doesn't have a default constructor, it requires you to specify year, month, day at a minimum.  You could just use tzinfo=None to indicate an unspecified date, since Python won't allow interactions between datetimes with and without tzinfo.